# Detecting white area similar to ball from grayscale images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to achieve below stuff with attached image.

1. white area recognition from 2 - 6 feet from threshold image(which i converted from grayscale image)
2. White area size to be recognized as a golf ball(golf balls have a diameter of about 45mm).
3. Max size of the white area that the app would recognize as a golf ball
4. The min size of the white area that the app would recognise as a golf ball would be depending on the results of the processed image.
5. IPhone 4 specs said 960-by-640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi . So pixel width is 1 inch / 326 pixels per inch or about 0.003067 inches per pixel or 0.0779 mm per pixel.
6. My goal is to detect major white area similar to ball and mark that area with red colour.
   I tried with houghcircle and findContours but it does not help me in that direction.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Grayscale image to detect ball]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide more detail about what approaches you've looked into and how they've failed? Otherwise this looks like a "build something for me" question, which doesn't fly too well on SO.

Comment: There's lots of research on computer vision problems like this out there. One good place to start might be the technique for using Core Image to detect objects described in [GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch26.html).

Comment: HI Rickster,i tried this and shown output image.
 IplImage *orgimage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplImage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"];
orgimage =[self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:image];
Mat matiplImage = Mat(iplImage);
Mat matRGB = Mat(orgimage);
IplImage *imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(orgimage), 8, 3);               cvCvtColor(orgimage, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
IplImage *imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(orgimage), 8, 1);
 cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(0.00, 0.00, 249.62), cvScalar(180.00 , 20.60, 256.00), imgThreshed);